# How to use published_date - Method in Telegram's instant view API?

Tags: api, xpath, xquery, telegram

I am trying to setup an [Instant View](https://instantview.telegram.org/docs) for a website. Everything's working fine, except the published_date aspect. As I found it, it needs an div-container (or similar) with date information. Than it has to be transformed to unixtime timestamp via "@datetime(-2): xpath_query". but how do I continue?

i.e:

I tried:

```
<div class="Date">19.05.2017</div>
$date: //div[has-class("Date")]
@datetime(-2): $date
published_date: $@
```

but this has no effect on the date. What am I doing wrong? The telegram manuel is too brief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to deal with it, so I use this dirty work for my template

```
$date: //div[has-class("Date")]/text()
@debug  # 19.05.2017
@replace("(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d\\d)\\.(\\d{4})", "$3/$2/$1"): $date
@debug  # 2017/05/19
published_date: $@
@debug  # 1495141200 (2017/05/19)
```

It convert 19.05.2017 to 2017/05/19, and then published_date can parse it.